# Injecting jaxws:endpoint configuration published URL

Tags: spring, spring-el

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="serviceEndpoint" implementor="#serviceImpl" address="/public/api/service/v1"" publishedEndpointUrl="#{serviceImpl.endpointUrl}"> </jaxws:endpoint> 

<bean id="serviceImpl" class="com.services.ServiceProviderImpl" autowire="byType"> </bean>
```

I need to populate **publishedEndpointUrl**  refering a variable in my implementor bean. (ServiceProviderImpl) Please let me know the way I can make it. I refereed http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html.

Making it `publishedEndpointUrl="#{serviceImpl}.publishedUrl"` does not make work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ServiceProviderImpl` has a public getter `getPublishedUrl()`, the syntax you need is

```
#{serviceImpl.publishedUrl}
```

In future, when adding questions here, "does not work" is not useful at all.

Always provide the error message and/or stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am getting below error.
      
Cannot resolve reference to bean '{serviceImpl.endpointUrl}' while setting bean property 'publishedEndpointUrl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '{serviceImpl.endpointUrl}' is defined

Comment: I am not familiar with [their xml parser](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/3.0.4/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/spring/EndpointDefinitionParser.java#EndpointDefinitionParser) but I don't see it parsing that attribute. The error implies it's looking for a bean rather than a string. But I'm on my iPad which is not really good for looking at code.

Comment: But I would still expect a SpEL error. Can you show your actual config? Did you leave off the `#` ?

Comment: also, I look for bean "serviceEndpoint" which is JAXWS Endpoint when Initializing Bean . Then In the afterPropertySet method I set the value  EndpointDefinitionParser.SpringEndpointImpl sei = (EndpointDefinitionParser.SpringEndpointImpl)bean;
        sei.setPublishedEndpointUrl(url); Still WSDL does not take this value

Comment: Please note that I am using Spring 2.5.1 and I am not in a position to upgrade my Spring version runs in production

Comment: SpEL didn't exist in 2.5.x; it was not introduced until 3.0, in 2009. You should use the [reference documentation pertaining to your version](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.1/reference/).